# Express js request continues to process even after return statement

Tags: node.js, express, pg-promise

In the below code snippet even when the second if condition is met and this is returned

```
return res.status(400).send({message: "This name is already in use. Please enter a new name"});
```

,the code still continues to execute and insert the data in the database.

Why is it happening and how can I stop that from executing any further?

```
db.task(async t => {
            const totalCustomTemplates = await t.manyOrNone(`SELECT * FROM Test WHERE propertyid = $1`, [
                propertyId,
            ]);

            if (totalCustomTemplates.length < 30 ) {

                //Check if the template name is unique and does not exist for the property already
                totalCustomTemplates.forEach(element => {
                    if(element.campaigntemplatename == templateName)
                    {
                        return res.status(400).send({message: "This name is already in use. Please enter a new name"});
                    }                    
                });

                await db.none('INSERT INTO Test(aid, bid, cid) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)',[a, b, c]);
                return res.status(200).send({message: "Template added successfully", template: {
                    campaignTemplateId: templateId,
                    templateName: templateName
                }});            
            }
            else{
                return res.status(400).send({message: "Max reached"});
            }
        });
```

Comment: That return statement ends the callback function of the `forEach` method; it doesn't ends the execution of the outer function. You could use tradition for loop or for-of loop to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I am new to javascript, where can I read more about this. I thought the foreach was just a pretty way to write for loop in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `some` function to check if the name is already used.
This will avoid the usage of the `forEach` and will block the execution if the condition is valid:

```
if (
  totalCustomTemplates.some(
    (element) => element.campaigntemplatename === templateName
  )
) {
  return res.status(400).send({
    message: 'This name is already in use. Please enter a new name',
  });
}
```

Comment: [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will shortcut the creation/check of the array